# Strange Webpage Font Rendering on Android

Tags: website-design, fonts, android

The following screenshot  is taken from a Nexus 6 browsing on Chrome 49 on Android 6.0.1. The "s" and "t" --- when they appear together --- are joined by a line. This is not intended. It renders fine everywhere else. QUESTION: Have you seen this or something similar before? Can you suggest avenues of research to solve?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GDSE. If you want to know more about the site, please see [the help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 6):

This is called a ligature. The tend to be very subtle, like the ones used for te `ff`, `fi` and `ffl` combinations. This one is... less so.

You can deactivate ligatures (all of them) using 
`-webkit-font-variant-ligatures: no-common-ligatures;`, but that will also get rid of the (useful) other ligatures.

You might want to check out [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19591746/prevent-ligatures-in-safari-mavericks-ios7-via-css) on the subject to further your search.

Comment: Ligatures require font support, and there are "regular ligatures" and "discretionary ligatures." The "st" is generally marked discretionary, so if it is not a chrome problem and not a code problem, perhaps the font itself marks them "improperly"